# How to extend a list with iterable and non-iterable object in one line?

Tags: python

Lets say I have 3 objects:

```
object1 = [1, 2, 3]
object2 = 'string'
object3 = {'key': 10}
```

I am trying to create a new list object in one line such that it looks like this:

```
object4 = [1, 2, 3, 'string', {'key': 10}]
```

Comment: Does `object1 +[object2]+[object3]` work for you?

Comment: It does. Although I get a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use unpacking for the iterables:

```
object4 = [*object1,object2,object3]
```

Comment: Thank you. Did not know about unpacking. I spent 30 minutes googling and couldn't find a solution. Follow up challenge question: If object 1, 2, and 3 were initially in a list. Could you get the same result without knowing which objects were iterable?

Comment: strings and dictionaries are iterable so it is an arbitrary decision on your part to determine which ones to unpack.  If that is strictly based on data types, you could write a function to do it but that is also an arbitrary choice.